# Google cloud tasks NodeJS api: Get queue stats?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-client, beta, google-cloud-tasks

I want to obtain the stats field for a queue in google cloud tasks using the nodejs client library `@google-cloud/tasks`. The stats field only exists in the `v2beta3` version, however to get it we need to pass a query params `readMask=*`, but I don't know how to pass it using the client lib.
I tried using the `otherArgs` params, but its not working.

```js
const tasks = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

const client = new tasks.v2beta3.GoogleCloudTasks()

// Get queue containing stats
const queue = await client.getQueue({name: '..'}, {otherArgs: {readMask: '*'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

The readMask specifies which paths of the response object to fetch. The response will include all possible paths with placeholders like null, UNSPECIFIED, etc. and then contain the actual values you want.

```
const request = {
    ...
    readMask: { paths: ['name', 'stats', 'state', ...] }
};
```

**getQueue**

```
const { v2beta3 } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const tasksClient = new v2beta3.CloudTasksClient();

async function main() {
    const request = {
        name: 'projects/PROJECT/locations/LOCATION/queues/QUEUE',
        readMask: { paths: ['name', 'stats'] }
    };

    const [response] = await tasksClient.getQueue(request);

    console.log(response);
}
main();

/*
{
  name: 'projects/PROJECT/locations/LOCATION/queues/QUEUE',
  ...
  stats: {
    tasksCount: '113',
    oldestEstimatedArrivalTime: null,
    executedLastMinuteCount: '0',
    concurrentDispatchesCount: '0',
    effectiveExecutionRate: 500
  }
}
*/
```

**listQueues**

```
const { v2beta3 } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const tasksClient = new v2beta3.CloudTasksClient();

async function main() {
    const request = {
        parent: 'projects/PROJECT/locations/LOCATION',
        readMask: { paths: ['name', 'stats'] }
    };

    const [response] = await tasksClient.listQueues(request);

    console.log(response);
}
main();

/*
[
  {
    name: 'projects/PROJECT/locations/LOCATION/queues/QUEUE',
    ...
    stats: {
      tasksCount: '1771',
      oldestEstimatedArrivalTime: [Object],
      executedLastMinuteCount: '0',
      concurrentDispatchesCount: '0',
      effectiveExecutionRate: 500
    }
  },
  ...
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at the [source code for the client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/src/v2beta3/cloud_tasks_client.ts)  I see no reference for the readMask parameter as specified on the [v2beta3 version of the REST API projects.locations.queues.get method](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues/get).

The relevant method on the NodeJS client library [getQueue()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/2.1.2/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.CloudTasks.html#getQueue1) expects a type of request [IGetQueueRequest](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/2.1.2/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.IGetQueueRequest.html) that doesn't have the `readMask` parameter and is only expecting the `name` property.

Nonetheless this implementation might change in the future to include a relevant method to get the stats.

Regarding the REST API itself, there is an error on the public docs on the [readMask section](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues/get#query-parameters) as * is not a valid character. If you want to get the Queue.stats field you should simply enter `stats` on the readMask parameter. If you want to get all the relevant fields you should enter all of them (e.g. `name,rateLimits,retryConfig,state,taskTtl,tombstoneTtl,type,stats` should get all the relevant fields you get from calling the method + the Queue.stats field).

The following picture should help you.[image: only return the Queue.stats field]

As a workaround if you click on the expand symbol on the Try this API section of the docs for the relevant method you could click on the JAVASCRIPT section and get the relevant code as how to build the request as shown on the following picture.[image: code in JS]

**EDIT JANUARY 23rd 2020**

The documentation was corrected to inform that in order to express that:

> [Queue.stats] will be returned only if it was explicitly specified in the mask.

Which translates that simply writing `stats` under the readMask field will return the stats.

Comment: That's a shame. The code you propose does need an API key and client id which is extra configuration.

Comment: Yes. You are correct! The benefit of the client libraries is that they handle the authentication and authorization under the hood through environment variables, but I don't see any other possibilities using JS. You can get the Queue.stats field using the Python Client Library though. I can post some code for it if you find it helpful.